# "make check" cannot find installed shared libraries

Tags: gcc4.8

Installing gcc 4.8, I am using the recommended infrastructure libs to reduce possible issues.

Built and installed gmp using default settings--> shared libs went to /usr/local/lib
Built isl, but make check cannot find the installed gmp shared lib.
Installed isl anyway, shared libs went to /usr/local/lib.
Built cloog, but make check also cannot find either the installed isl or gmp shared libs

So I went into cloog-0.18.0/.libs/ and made soft links to /usr/local/lib/libisl.so.10.1.1 and libgmp.so.3 and re-ran make check without any failures.

These are the recommended infastructure tarballs downloaded from the gcc ftp server, and built and installed using a default configuration. Why might "make check" be unable to find the shared libraries it just installed?

should add: this is a new Ubuntu installation

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that /usr/local/lib is in your global shared library config -- check /etc/ld.so.conf -- /usr/local/lib should be there or in one of the files it includes.  If its not, add it and run `ldconfig` as root to rebuild the cache.

Comment: In /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ libc.conf has 
/usr/local/lib

Comment: WHatever was causing the problem, running ldconfig  fixed it.  THANK YOU